# Embedding font in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uifont

I have embedded font in ios, like the normal version italics and all by following methodes.

1.Added font to project folder.
2.Added font names "MuseoSans_100.otf" inside "Fonts provided by application" in info.plist.
3. created UIFont in viewdidload method

```
     UIFont *newfont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MuseoSans_100" size:13.0];
    [labelname setFont:newfont];
```

but when i run this in simulator, i can see the font and size are not changing.

Please help.

Comment: You can follow this easy step by step guide to achieve it: [Adding Custom Fonts to Your iOS App](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)

Comment: i have accepted your answer

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the fontNamesForFamilyName: method to retrieve the specific font names for a given font family.

Check the font family

```
NSLog(@"%@",[UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"MuseoSans_100"]);
```